# Laravel | Polymorphic Relationship unknown column

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, models

This is my first time using a polymorphic relationship.

I am creating a LMS where a Assignment can be allocated to a individual user or a team so reading the Laravel docs it seems that the Polymorphic Relationship will be a good way to go about it.

I have created 4 tables.

Users:
`| id | username   | password | created_at | updated_at |`

Teams: `| id | friendly_name | slug |`

Team User: `| id | user_id | team_id |`

Assignment Allocation:

`| id | assignment_id | assignmentable_type | assignmentable_id | created_at | updated_at`

So when the `assignment_allocations` has data in it looks like this...

`| id | assignment_id | assignmentable_type | assignmentable_id |
| 1  |             1 | App\Models\User     |                 1 |`

However I get this error:

> SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`assignmentable_id` = 1 and `users`.`assignmentable_id` is not null and `users`.`assignmentable_type` = App\Models\User

SO obviously I have done something wrong, however I cannot for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong.

This is my functions that relate to this:

`AssignmentAllocation.php`

```
public function assignmentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

`User.php`

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\User', 'assignmentable');
}
```

`Team.php`

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Model\Team', 'assignmentable');
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 potential answers depending on your data structure, which isn't clear from your question.

1. `User`/`Team` to `Assignment` is a one-to-many relationship (each `Assignment` has one `User`/`Team`, and each `User`/`Team` has many `Assignments`
2. Many-to-many relationship where each `User`/`Team` has many `Assignments` and each `Assignment` has many `Users`/`Teams`

---

**One to many**

In a one-to-many you wouldn't need an `Assignment` table **and** an `AssignmentAllocation` table, so I am assuming your `AssignmentAllocation` is your `Assignment` model. If not then you need to put the `assignmentable_type` and `assignmentable_id` columns on the `assignments` table instead, and use `Assignment.php` instead of `AssignmentAllocation.php`.

`AssignmentAllocation.php`

```
public function assignmentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

`User.php`

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\AssignmentAllocation', 'assignmentable');
}
```

`Team.php`

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\AssignmentAllocation', 'assignmentable');
}
```

Your error is because Laravel is searching the `users` table for the match (you have `morphMany('User'..`), when it should be searching the `AssignmentAllocation` table. So just switch them out.

1) The `morphMany` acts like a `hasMany`, so you're saying:

Each `User` `hasMany` `Assignment`s, and each `Team` `hasMany` `Assignments`. The first part of the `morphMany` says "search the `AssignmentAllocation` table", and the second part says "search for `assignmentable`_id and `assignmentable`_type being equal to this instance of this model".

2) `morphTo` acts like `belongsTo` so you're saying:

Each `Assignment` `belongsTo` an `assignmentable`.

---

**Many to many**

However if `AssignmentAllocation` is a many-to-many pivot table and each `Assignment` has many `Users` or `Teams`, and each `User`/`Team` has many `Assignments`, then you need a `morphToMany`/`morphedByMany` pair.

`User.php`

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Assignment', 'assignmentable');
}
```

`Team.php`

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Assignment', 'assignmentable');
}
```

`Assignment.php` model *NOTE: not the AssignmentAllocation model*

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\User', 'assignmentable');
}

public function teams()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Team', 'assignmentable');
}
```

You should rename the `assignment_allocation` table to `assignmentables`, or add the required third and fourth arguments to the morph functions. I prefer to keep the table names consistent.