# Laravel Polymorphic Relationship Multiple Types

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm struggling to model the relationships in the following scenario.

Types of model - Node - Connection - Button

- A `Node` has 0-many inputs() which can be either from a `Node` or a `Button`.
- A `Node` is connected to its input(s) using `Connection` pivots.
- A `Node` has 0-one output() to another `Node`. Again via a `Connection`.
- A `Node` has 0-n `Button`s. // easy to implement, ignore
- A `Button` belongs to a `Node`. // easy to implement, ignore
- A `Button` has 0-one output() to a `Node` via a `Connection`.

Ideal API

```
$node1->output()->save($node2); // link two nodes
$node1->inputs()->save($node2); // links two nodes
$button->output()->save($node1); // links a button and a node
$node1->inputs()->save($button); // links a node and a button

// replace save() with attach() or associate(), I forget which it is!
```

`Connection::all()` should give me all connections with their

- source_id which is either a `Node` id, or a `Button` id.
- source_type which is either `node` or `button`.
- destination_id which is a `Node` id.

Roughly assumed model property types in case that helps visualise it.

- `$button->node` = `Node`
- `$button->output` = `Node|null`
- `$button->output->pivot` = `Connection`
- `$node->output` = `Node|null`
- `$node->output->pivot` = `Connection`
- `$node->inputs` = `Collection<Node|Button>|null`
- `$connection->destination` = `Node`
- `$connection->source` = `Node|Button`

[image]

I think my primary problem is that the polymorphic relationships require you to set the type of the model you're morphing to rather than taking it from the model you're passing in so I'm struggling to work out how the `Node` `inputs()` method would work as a `morphToMany()` requires I specify a model, which i need to pass either a `Node` or a `Button`.

--

I found these stack overflow questions but couldn't seem to map them to my use case.

- [Laravel | Polymorphic Relationship unknown column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536404/laravel-polymorphic-relationship-unknown-column)
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/polymorphic-many-to-many-relation-to-multiple-models

Comment: I think this might be of use to you. I don't have the time to think it through properly right now, but at-a-glance, I think  this package is what you're looking for. 
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this some more, I am not sure why we are using polymorphic here.

If you do have a deeper reason for wanting polymorphic here my following solution will not work.

Migrations:

```
Schema::create('nodes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('buttons', function (Blueprint $table) {             
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('node_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('connections', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('input_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('output_id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('input_id')->references('id')->on('nodes');
    $table->foreign('output_id')->references('id')->on('nodes');
});
```

Connection Model

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Connection extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'connections';
    
    public function input()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Node::class, 'input_id');
    }

    public function output()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Node::class, 'output_id');
    }
}
```

Node Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

class Node extends Model
{
    public function inputs()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Node::class,
            Connection::class,
            'output_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'input_id'
        );
    }

    public function output()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            Node::class,
            Connection::class,
            'input_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'output_id'
        );
    }

    public function connection()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Connection::class, 'output_id');
    }

    public function buttons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Button::class);
    }
}
```

Button Model

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

class Button extends Model
{
    public function node()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Node::class);
    }
}
```

Now you can't do everything exactly as smoothly as you wanted without adding some extra/fancier relations to button.

```
$button->node = Node (Works)
$button->output = Node|null ($button->node->output)
$button->output->pivot = Connection ($button->connection)
$node->output = Node|null (Works)
$node->output->pivot = Connection ($node->connection)
$node->inputs = Collection<Node|Button>|null (Works)
$connection->destination = Node ($connection->output)
$connection->source = Node|Button ($connection->input)
```

Hope that helps. If you do truly need polymorphic relations I can think more about it later.

*** Edit ****

After re-reading your question, my answer is formulated on this statement:

A Button belongs to a Node. // easy to implement, ignore

Which makes $connection->source = Node|Button, untrue in my solution

You would need $connection->input->buttons()->...

Comment: Thanks, Kurt. The problem with this solution is it unfortunately doesn't solve the bit I mentioned i was primarily struggling with; that an input can be a Node or a Button. In your example the input must always be a Node.

Comment: I will think more about it. Definitely doable.

Comment: Thanks! That's my thinking too I just can't quite get there yet.

Comment: Should you change the part of your question that references a button belonging to a node be changed to it belonging to a connection? Or is it both?

Comment: It is both. The node can have many buttons, but it is the button itself which is subsequently connected to another node. The buttons effectively represent multiple outputs of the node. If there are no buttons, the single output of a node is used as a hasOne effectively. The use case is if a single output with no buttons exists, the next Node via an output can be immediately picked. If there are buttons, the user makes a choice to indicate which node they want to go to next. For the sake of argument here though the Node hasMany Buttons relationship can be ignored as it (probably?).